# Cant change state redux data from server react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I cant change redux state if its not predefined in initial state.
This is my initial state

```
var InitialState = Record({
   ....
   mode: null
   data:[]
})
```

When there is json from server, it will be in `data`.

The data will contain like id, bookmark, name, etc

I can access the data from server `this.props.search.data.bookmark` but I cant update it, I think it cant find `bookmark` state. 
I can update `mode` state since its in initial state.

Example data in json

```
{id:1 ,Bookmark:true},
{id:2 ,Bookmark:true},
.....
```

In short
I tried to do this
This works

```
console.log(state.getIn(['search', 'mode]))
```

But this doesnt work, (undefined)

```
console.log(state.getIn(['search', 'data', 'bookmark']))
```

if I add `fromJS` on the reducer payload when set the data, I can access them

```
case SET_DATA:
      return state.set('data', fromJS(action.payload))
```

now this work

```
console.log(state.getIn(['search', 'data', 'bookmark']))
```

but on my containers I got error

> TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'this.props.search.data.map')

I cant use map for looping.

How is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It makes no difference what is in the initial state, whatever you return from your reducer determines the state from that point on. Can you share enough code to completely reproduce the problem? There isn't enough here to go on. Include the entire reducer, mapStateToProps and the call to `connect()`, and ideally the component that is using the data.

Comment: It seems odd that you set data to be an array `[]` in the initial state, but later you access it like an object. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: I edited the question, I am not sure if its about object or array. I tried using getIn to get the bookmark

Comment: Need to see a complete code example to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, it looks like you're not returning anything from your reducer. Assuming you're using immutablejs, `setIn()` returns a copy of the state. Your code is currently throwing that value away (not using it). You probably want to return that copy. Try this:

```
case BOOKMARK:
   return state.setIn(['search', 'data', 'bookmark'], action.payload.total)
```

The only difference is the `return` keyword.

Comment: There is return, I just forgot to type it on the question